# Plot time series graph using Bokeh?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dic = {'2017-08-11': {'Yes': 157, 'Not sure': 2, 'No': 1}, '2017-08-22': {'Yes': 142, 'Not sure': 12}, '2017-08-01': {'Yes': 112, 'Others': 10, 'Not sure': 4, 'No': 9}, '2017-08-17': {'Yes': 117, 'No': 12, 'Not sure': 11, 'Others': 2}, '2017-08-25': {'Yes': 61, 'Not sure': 9}, '2017-08-23': {'Yes': 268, 'Not sure': 20, 'No': 1}, '2017-07-10': {'Yes': 123, 'Not sure': 4, 'No': 1}, '2017-08-10': {'Yes': 343, 'Not sure': 20}, '2017-07-13': {'Yes': 116, 'Others': 1, 'Not sure': 14, 'No': 2}, '2017-07-14': {'Yes': 255, 'Not sure': 22, 'No': 6}, '2017-08-07': {'Yes': 73, 'Others': 3, 'Not sure': 4, 'No': 5}, '2017-08-04': {'Not sure': 11, 'Others': 8, 'Yes': 178, 'No': 10}, '2017-08-16': {'Not sure': 10, 'Yes': 219}, '2017-07-18': {'Yes': 1, 'No': 1}, '2017-08-15': {'Yes': 301, 'Others': 4, 'Not sure': 37, 'No': 31}, '2017-08-08': {'Yes': 38, 'No': 2, 'Others': 1}, '2017-08-09': {'Yes': 120, 'Not sure': 3}, '2017-08-28': {'Yes': 206, 'Others': 2, 'Not sure': 18, 'No': 24}, '2017-08-14': {'Yes': 46, 'No': 3, 'Not sure': 5, 'Others': 7}}
```

Then I use the dictionary to generate a time series graph using Bokeh:

```
from bokeh.charts import TimeSeries
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from dateutil.parser import parse
output_notebook()
list_x = []
list_y = []
for i in dic:
    list_x.append(i)
    list_y.append(round(float(dic[i]['Yes'])/float(sum(dic[i].values()))*100, 2))
df_date = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Precision'])
df_date['Date'] = list_x
df_date['Precision'] = list_y
df_date.sort_values('Date', ascending=True, inplace=True)
x = df_date['Date'].tolist()
y = df_date['Precision'].tolist()
data = dict(Precision = y, Date = [parse(s) for s in x])
p = TimeSeries(data, ylabel='Precision(%)')
output_file("timeseries.html")
show(p)
```

The [result](http://www.clipular.com/c/6659335001473024.png?k=eAuZgZGcNkSEwyKH41qzB5ChzT4) does not show the dates on the x-axis, would be glad if someone could help me out, thanks!

Comment: Libraries like Bokeh usually support various different input formats. Try it out using small "mock" examples. Then, try to get there from your original data in the smallest number of steps (you convert your data like 5 times!). Besides, consider using Python3, the death clock for Python2 is ticking!

Comment: @thanks for the inputs!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`TimeSeries` is part of the old `bokeh.charts` API that has been removed to a separate new `bkcharts` project. It is currently unmaintained, and I would strongly discourage its use. But, you can create time series plots with the stable `bokeh.plotting` API easily enough. Here is minimal example using your data (I've also updated to use Pandas better, and not have explicit loops)

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

dic = {'2017-08-11': {'Yes': 157, 'Not sure': 2, 'No': 1}, '2017-08-22': {'Yes': 142, 'Not sure': 12}, '2017-08-01': {'Yes': 112, 'Others': 10, 'Not sure': 4, 'No': 9}, '2017-08-17': {'Yes': 117, 'No': 12, 'Not sure': 11, 'Others': 2}, '2017-08-25': {'Yes': 61, 'Not sure': 9}, '2017-08-23': {'Yes': 268, 'Not sure': 20, 'No': 1}, '2017-07-10': {'Yes': 123, 'Not sure': 4, 'No': 1}, '2017-08-10': {'Yes': 343, 'Not sure': 20}, '2017-07-13': {'Yes': 116, 'Others': 1, 'Not sure': 14, 'No': 2}, '2017-07-14': {'Yes': 255, 'Not sure': 22, 'No': 6}, '2017-08-07': {'Yes': 73, 'Others': 3, 'Not sure': 4, 'No': 5}, '2017-08-04': {'Not sure': 11, 'Others': 8, 'Yes': 178, 'No': 10}, '2017-08-16': {'Not sure': 10, 'Yes': 219}, '2017-07-18': {'Yes': 1, 'No': 1}, '2017-08-15': {'Yes': 301, 'Others': 4, 'Not sure': 37, 'No': 31}, '2017-08-08': {'Yes': 38, 'No': 2, 'Others': 1}, '2017-08-09': {'Yes': 120, 'Not sure': 3}, '2017-08-28': {'Yes': 206, 'Others': 2, 'Not sure': 18, 'No': 24}, '2017-08-14': {'Yes': 46, 'No': 3, 'Not sure': 5, 'Others': 7}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient="index")
df = df.fillna(0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index.name = 'Date'
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df['Total'] = df.Yes + df['Not sure'] + df.No + df.Others
df['Precision'] = round(df.Yes/df.Total, 2)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, plot_height=350)
p.line('Date', 'Precision', source=source)

output_file("ts.html")
show(p)
```

Which yields

[image]

Comment: got an error:  AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'

Comment: @JasonLi I don't get an issue with this exact code. But there is one place in Bokeh that tries to use pandas.tslib, soI presume you are trying on code with pandas TimeStamps in it? Looks like Pandas removed pandas.tslib in a recent version: forum.knime.com/t/… Can you file a Bokeh GitHub issue about this so that we can figure out how to work around the Pandas change?

Comment: Actually, this was already fixed [some time ago in version 0.12.6](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6274), if you are seeing this, you must be using a very old version of Bokeh.